# "user.setStatus" doesn't update bot's status Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, gamedig

I would like that when the game server is detected as offline, the status becomes orange (`idle`), and when the server is online, the status becomes green (`online`).

For this, I used `client.user.setStatus('online')` and `client.user.setStatus('idle')` but the status does not change, only the message is updated.

Here is my code:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('OK')

  setInterval(() => {
    Gamedig.query({
      type: 'garrysmod',
      host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
      port: '27015'
    })
      .then((updatedState) => {
        state = updatedState;

        const nb_joueursmax = state.maxplayers;
        const nb_joueurs = state.players.length;
        
        client.user.setStatus('online');
        client.user.setActivity(`${nb_joueurs}/${nb_joueursmax} Joueurs`);  
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        client.user.setStatus('idle');
        client.user.setActivity('Serveur Hors Ligne');
      });
  }, 6000);
});
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work. Only the message is updated, not the status...

Comment: Redefine *'“user.setStatus” does works Discord.JS'!*  What does it do right now? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an error and it should work fine, it probably is just slow to react/update. You could also use `setPresence` to update the status and the activity with a single command:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('OK');

  setInterval(() => {
    Gamedig.query({
      type: 'garrysmod',
      host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
      port: '27015',
    })
      .then((updatedState) => {
        state = updatedState;

        const nb_joueursmax = state.maxplayers;
        const nb_joueurs = state.players.length;

        client.user.setPresence({
          activity: { name: `${nb_joueurs}/${nb_joueursmax} Joueurs` },
          status: 'online',
        });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        client.user.setPresence({
          activity: { name: 'Serveur Hors Ligne' },
          status: 'idle',
        });
      });
  }, 6000);
});
```

Comment: Hi, it's same, I just noticed that (status) this changes 10 minutes later...